# Security level of FHE constructions for non-standard parameters

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, provable-security, ring-lwe

[homomorphicencryption](http://homomorphicencryption.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/HomomorphicEncryptionStandardv1.1.pdf) standards already provide recommended parameters and their corresponding security levels. However, I would like to calculate a security level for nonstandard parameter selection.

Is there an simple way to calculate the security level?

Comment: I don't think you should do that if you're planning on actually *using* your parameter selection. In general, these estimates come from a vast and complex body of research on lattice-based cryptography. There are many parameters involved as you may know (noise, deviation, dimension, etc.) and the truth is that only a handful of people know their relations and concrete sizes. The homomorphic encryption standardization is precisely an effort to take this knowledge to a more general public, for a concrete set of parameters.

Comment: While I agree that this would be useful, that doesn't mean that there shouldn't be a well defined method of deriving at those numbers for those who want to check them. That said, the question asks for a **simple** way. If there isn't such a thing (or a likewise loosely correct one) then yeah, the question may have a negative result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *standard* way is by using [the LWE estimator](https://lwe-estimator.readthedocs.io) (if it is *simple* or not it is debatable).

It estimates the cost of known attacks against LWE instances given parameters
$n$, $\alpha$, and $q$, where $\alpha$ represents the noise ratio and can be obtained from the parameter $\sigma$ from the discrete Gaussian using the formula $\alpha = \sqrt{2 \pi} \cdot \sigma / q$, already implemented in command `alpha = alphaf(sigmaf(sigma), q)`.

The estimator basically finds the block size $\beta$ that the BKZ algorithm will have to use to break the LWE problem. But estimating the running time of BKZ-$\beta$ is not simple, so, to get the actual security level, you have to choose a cost model for BKZ.

In short, BKZ runs on a lattice of dimension $d$ and does several calls to a SVP solver in dimension $\beta$. The SVP oracle is often assumed to require $2^{0.292\cdot \beta}$ operations in a classical computer and $2^{0.265\cdot \beta}$ in a quantum one.
Thus, using `reduction_cost_model=BKZ.sieve` in the LWE estimator will give you the number of operations as $2^{0.292\cdot \beta + 16.4 + \log_2(8 \cdot d)}$ and you want it to be larger than $2^\lambda$ for $\lambda$ bits of security.

Some people are more conservative (paranoid?) and ignore cost related to the dimension $d$ and the many calls to the SVP oracle, therefore they estimate the number of operations of BKZ as a single call to the SVP solver, thus, they get $2^{0.292\cdot \beta}$ or $2^{0.265\cdot \beta}$. This is called the "core-SVP" cost model and it was used, for example, to estimate the security of [SABER](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/pqcrypto/saber/).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I ran the estimator and got following outcome:                     sage: a = alphaf(sigmaf(3.2), 2^124)
sage: n = 4096; q = 2^124 ; alpha = a
sage: costs = estimate_lwe(n, alpha, q)
usvp: rop: ≈2^161.8,  red: ≈2^161.8,  δ_0: 1.005117,  β:  276,  d: 8199,  m:  ≈2^12.0
....  ——————— I am not sure how to get estimate out of it, can you please guide a bit more. Thanks very much

Comment: This is telling you that the number of operations needed by BKZ to break LWE in the unique-SVP attack is approx $2^{161.8}$, so the security level is $\lambda > 161$ (considering the other attacks printed out cost more than this). But you did not specify the cost model and I don't know which one the estimator uses by default. Also, this is probably supposing that the key is uniform in Z_q^n. It would be good to use something like `estimate_lwe(n, alpha, q, secret_distribution=(0,1), reduction_cost_model=BKZ.sieve)` to choose the cost model and the distribution of sk as the one you are using.

Comment: got it I set parameters with secret key distribution as in SEAL (I am using seal) and BKZ.sieve cost model and it gives 111 bits of security .. thanks for your answer